# Should we store ALL data on firebase of just the latest version?

Tags: ios, firebase

Our app relates very closely to the [SF Bus example](https://github.com/firebase/firebus) posted by Firebase, as we also track vehicles and their passengers.

Is is recommended to store all the location data of the vehicles on Firebase or should we only store the latest version and keep everything else on a separate database?

I am wondering this because the only data that is **real-time relevant** is the **latest location of a vehicle**.

For our real-time app, we dont care where the vehicle has been, we want to know where the vehicle is now. The logs are stored for later analysis.

What would be the SO recommendation on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Firebase founder here] I'd recommend only storing the current location of the vehicles. Firebase's strength is in real-time updates and scaling, so it's ideal for broadcasting vehicle position out to large numbers of people. It's not great for data-mining activities though. So if you want to store histories and do analysis on them, I'd recommend storing that in a separate system designed for complex analysis.